# change defult label of prime ng multiselect

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select, primeng-dropdowns

I am using multiselect component from prime ng. I am trying to change the label of the multiselect dropdown but it does not work. Please find my code below:

```
                <p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [defaultLabel]="does not work" styleClass="citiesClass" (onChange)="onChange($event)">
                </p-multiSelect>
```

How do I change default label for the multiselect component ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `defaultLabel="Your Label"` or `[defaultLabel]="'Your Label'"`

Try like this:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" defaultLabel="Your Label" styleClass="citiesClass" (onChange)="onChange($event)">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Note: If you have the string in the variable,

Use: `[defaultLabel]="labelVariable"`

If it is a hardcoded string, then

Use: `defaultLabel="Your Label"`

Comment: The version you mentioned above without square brackets worked. But if the cities array is getting modified by some other external sources, the label disappears. So, back to square one. - thanks

Comment: yeah, it worked. whenever I am resetting the dropdown data, I use this.multi._defaultLabel="label" along with your code. thanks.